# Cannot access private member (operator=) of QXmlStreamReader

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class with multiple members and methods. When I tried to add new member - QXmlStreamReader I got an error pointing to the end of my class:

```
C2248: 'QXmlStreamReader::QXmlStreamReader' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QXmlStreamReader'
```

Simplified class:

```
class Foo
{
    // multiple methods and class members which until now has been working fine
    QXmlStreamReader stream;
};
```

I was trying to use pointer instead but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find answer on the internet and I want to share my solution for this because it was a bit tricky to find this out. Somewhere in my code I had function like this:

```
void bar(Foo a_foo)
{   
    // example use
    a_foo.stream.setDevice(nullptr);
}
```

Function tries to use a COPY of Foo class but this cannot be done. Why? Because QXmlStreamReader doesn't have copy constructor (the same as QXmlStreamWriter, QFile etc) or overloaded operator=. Solution for this will be using reference to object rather than copy.

```
void bar(Foo& a_foo) // add reference '&' here!
{   
    // example use
    a_foo.stream.setDevice(nullptr);
}
```

Comment: The main reason you'd not want it done is because `bar` is meant to alter `a_foo`'s state, and you were trying to alter the local state instead. It doesn't matter that `a_foo` cannot be copied: you didn't mean to copy it to begin with! The issue with `QXmlStreamWriter` was just a happy coincidence that led you to the real bug. There's no "answer on the internet" because you didn't diagnose the problem correctly. Once you diagnose it, the answer is obvious: `bar`'s declaration was not agreeing with its specification. `bar`'s spec goes something like "Modify a_foo as follows [...]".